# Getting error "Missing statement for annotation" by passing the array of annotation into another annotation

Tags: java, scala, annotations

Getting error "Missing statement for annotation" by passing the array of annotation into another annotation in java. Code looks like this :

```
public @interface Big {
    String abc() default "";
}

public @interface B {
    String name() default "";
    Big[] big() default {};
}
```

The following class in scala

```
@B(name = "Reema",big = {@Big(abc = "a"), @Big(abc = "b")})
class MainTest() {
    ...
}
```

I tried the above code and it is giving me the error : "Missing statement for annotation" in the scala class.
I want to resolve the compiler issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make nested annotations work in Scala you have to use them like this:

```scala
  @B(
    name = "Reema",
    big = Array(new Big(abc = "a"), new Big(abc = "b"))
  )
  class MainTest() {...}
```